# iOS Blank View/Screen & Hang on Google Sign-In from viewDidLoad (only on repeated signin)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, google-signin

I've come across a bit of an issue with Google Drive Sign-In. I've narrowed it down quite a bit, and produced a very minimal repro.

The issue is I try to sign the user in when the View Controller first appears (viewDidLoad). It is a file browser view, allowing the user to select a file from his/her Google Drive. This works fine on first load, and used to work all the time with the old Google Drive integration I had.

Now, however, when a user:

1. Segues to File Browser View and signs in
2. Segues back to the main view
3. Decides to sign out, or otherwise becomes signed out of Google
4. Segues back to the File Browser view (viewDidLoad gets called again and GoogleDrive signIn)...

The sign-in controller appears to attempt to load but it just remains completely blank and there is no way back out of this situation. The app, appears hung.

Has anyone else had this problem, is it known? You can run this minimal repro to see the issue for yourself here:

https://github.com/mmcguill/google-objc-signin-problem-minimal-repro

I have found that by using a delay as shown below, the problem no longer occurs. As you can imagine, this isn't something I really want to do in my app, it feels fairly hacky.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{    
    GIDSignIn* signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.delegate = self;
    signIn.uiDelegate = self;
    [signIn signIn];
});
```

This is happening with Cocoapod:

pod 'Google/SignIn', '~> 3.0.3'

on iPhone simulators, and on an actual iPhone 7. Not sure about other devices, though I'd imagine it's the same.

Any other suggestions for a clean workaround would be great. I do however want my view's behaviour to remain the same (Show Google Drive on Launch, popup sign in if not signed in)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the uiDelegate in the UIViewController where you're calling `[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] singIn];` from

Then before presenting the passed view controller in
`- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;` just call `[viewController view];` this should force the UI to be loaded before presented.

I experienced this behaviour also on iPhone7 iOS11 and that seemed to fix it